# Applying a wrapper function to an imported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

So I'm having issues accessing data with Immutable.js nested Reports.

I seem to have found a solution here [by AndrewBestbier](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/385#issuecomment-179347662) but I'm having trouble actually applying it to my code.

The solutions says that `fromJS()` an imported function from immutable.js accepts a "reviver" function. It then goes on to provide some kind of wrapper function here:

```
Record.constructor.prototype.fromJS = function(values) {
  var nested = fromJS(values, function(key, value){
    //See https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS for docs on custom reviver functions
    if(this.prototype[key] && this.prototype[key].constructor.prototype instanceof Record){
      return this.prototype[key].constructor.fromJS(value.toJS()); //use toJS() here if nest more than once
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }.bind(this));
  console.log()
  return this(nested);
};
```

I'm not sure how exactly I apply this to my code:

```
import { fromJS, mergeDeep, OrderedMap, Record } from 'immutable'

// Putting the suggested function here doesn't seem to do anything
// I must be missing some steps to get fromJS() to work with this 
// wrapper code.

const mergeEntities = (state, payload) => {
  return state.merge(payload.map( (id) => new Entity(id) ))
}

return mergeEntities(state, fromJS(action.payload.entities));
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

**EDIT:**

Here's an excerpt of my exported Records file:

```
const EntityRecord = new Record({
  id: undefined,
  status: "",
  messages: new Message(),
  redirectTo: "",
  entityType: "",
  isFetching: undefined,
  lang: "",
  title: "",
  charset: "",
  viewport: "",
  description: "",
  keywords: "",
  forms: new Form(),
  socialLoginText: "",
  forgotPasswordLinkText: "",
  registerLinkText: ""
});

class Entity extends EntityRecord{

}

export default Entity
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like according to your linked example, you're expected to invoke the `fromJS` method on the model instead of the `fromJS` function directly. I'm not that familiar with `immutable.js`, but assuming that your `Entity` is derived from the `Record` class, I think it would look something like this:

```
import { fromJS, mergeDeep, OrderedMap, Record } from 'immutable'

Record.constructor.prototype.fromJS = function(values) {
  var nested = fromJS(values, function(key, value){
    //See https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS for docs on custom reviver functions
    if(this.prototype[key] && this.prototype[key].constructor.prototype instanceof Record){
      return this.prototype[key].constructor.fromJS(value.toJS()); //use toJS() here if nest more than once
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }.bind(this));
  console.log()
  return this(nested);
};

const mergeEntities = (state, payload) => {
  return state.merge(payload.map( (id) => new Entity(id) ))
}

return mergeEntities(state, Entity.fromJS(action.payload.entities));
```

Comment: Yea I did try that before but it gave me this error ```TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__records__.a.fromJS is not a function```